# Suppressing output of a console application when invoked from Python script

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm working on a school project and I have to run John the Ripper through as a Python script.

Currently I'm running the command like this:

```
subprocess.run(['john --wordlist=/usr/share/john/password.lst --format=sha512crypt /root/Desktop/passwd '], shell=True)
```

My issue here is that it prints a lot of the process in the command terminal and I can't have anything show up in the terminal.

How can I make it so it doesn't print anything in the terminal?

Comment: add `> /dev/null` to the end of your first argument

Comment: That got rid of part of it, but there are still some parts of the process appearing in the terminal.

Comment: is it absolutely necessary to use `shell=True`? you can always use `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE` to pipe all output to python by doing `.communicate()`

Comment: @RockyLi I tried your suggestion and it's throwing me an error for some reason. Saying I can't find a file? Maybe I'm doing something wrong. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @RockyLi nevermind. I was doing the parameters wrong in my subprocess.run. Seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect the print so it dumps it in a file instead of printing on the terminal.
You might want to add something like after your code.

```
f = open("test.py", "w+")
print(output.stdout,f.write(output.stdout))
```

If you do `cat test.py` you should see the output.